# How to send an array in email via ajax and php

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

am a learner and I need your assistance. I have an online form for job application where you can list past jobs and enter referees. The problem is I want to send the details, which are in arrays but can't seem to catch a break.
This is the html form

```
<fieldset>
    <h2>7: Referees</h2>
<div class="row clone3">    


 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name[]" placeholder="Name">
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">Contact (Email)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone[]" placeholder="Referee contact">
  </div>

     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">Contact (Mobile)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email[]" placeholder="Referee contact">
  </div>


    </div>  
             <div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12" align="center"><a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone3">Add Another Referee</a></div><br/><br/></div>


    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit btn btn-success" value="Submit Application" id="form-submit" />
      <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
</fieldset>
```

This is the script to process the form

```
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Did you fill in the form properly?");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});


function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Message Sent! We'll get back shortly. Thank you! ")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

Below is the php code to send the form via email.

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// PHONE
if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Phone number is required ";
} else {
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
}


$EmailTo = "xyz@gmail.com";
$Subject = "New Application From the Website";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Phone: ";
$Body .= $phone;
$Body .= "\n";


// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

Now, the problem is the form only sends the email as one referee, even if I enter several referees.

Comment: "the details, which are in arrays"...are they, where? You've only got one textbox for each field in your code example. I'm going to assume that actually you are cloning these fields in your page? If so, it doesn't matter because your ajax only picks up one unique email field, one unique phone field etc. Try serialising your form instead using jquery's serialize method, and also watch out for duplicate HTML ids, which would render your page invalid.